# Left join duplicating and count ALL Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute query below with different result, but with no success.

```
SELECT a.Nome
      ,c.Saldo
      ,COUNT(d.Apostador_ID) AS Depositos
      ,COUNT(s.Apostador_ID) AS Saques
FROM Apostadores a
LEFT JOIN Contas c ON a.ID = c.Apostador_ID
LEFT JOIN Deposito d ON a.ID = d.Apostador_ID
LEFT JOIN Saque s ON a.ID = s.Apostador_ID
GROUP BY a.Nome, c.Saldo
```

It is returning:

```
Nome    Saldo   Depositos   Saques  
Marcos  4857      180        180    
Paulo   2868      180        180    
Mariana 8348      180        180    
Marcela -3512     180        180    
Mario   -2367     180        180    
Maria   -3359     180        180
```

But the result should be 27 for each of them.

Thanks!!

EDIT 1 :

```
INSERT INTO Apostadores
    (`ID`, `Nome`, `CPF`, `Email`)
VALUES
    (NULL, 'Marcos', '12345678901', 'marcos@email.com'),
    (NULL, 'Paulo', '12345678902', 'paulo@email.com'),
    (NULL, 'Mariana', '12345678903', 'mariana@email.com'),
    (NULL, 'Marcela', '12345678904', 'marcela@email.com'),
    (NULL, 'Mario', '12345678905', 'mario@email.com'),
    (NULL, 'Maria', '12345678906', 'maria@email.com');


INSERT INTO Contas
    (`ID`, `Apostador_ID`, `Saldo`)
VALUES
    (NULL, '1', '700.00'),
    (NULL, '2', '1000.00'),
    (NULL, '3', '5000.00'),
    (NULL, '4', '250.00'),
    (NULL, '5', '365.00'),
    (NULL, '6', '391.82');

INSERT INTO Deposito
    (`ID`, `Apostador_ID`, `Valor_Depositado`)
VALUES
    (NULL, '1', '700'),
    (NULL, '2', '900'),
    (NULL, '3', '580'),
    (NULL, '4', '260'),
    (NULL, '5', '360'),
    (NULL, '6', '154'),
    (NULL, '1', '1000'),
    (NULL, '2', '1346'),
    (NULL, '3', '2005'),
    (NULL, '4', '360'),
    (NULL, '5', '392'),
    (NULL, '6', '182'),
    (NULL, '1', '362'),
    (NULL, '2', '182'),
    (NULL, '3', '270'),
    (NULL, '4', '390'),
    (NULL, '5', '160'),
    (NULL, '6', '380'),
    (NULL, '1', '290'),
    (NULL, '2', '370'),
    (NULL, '3', '193'),
    (NULL, '4', '256'),
    (NULL, '5', '509'),
    (NULL, '6', '536'),
    (NULL, '1', '500'),
    (NULL, '2', '190'),
    (NULL, '3', '160'),
    (NULL, '4', '380'),
    (NULL, '5', '190'),
    (NULL, '6', '170');


INSERT INTO Saque
    (`ID`, `Apostador_ID`, `Valor_Sacado`)
VALUES
    (NULL, '1', '100'),
    (NULL, '2', '200'),
    (NULL, '3', '100'),
    (NULL, '4', '50'),
    (NULL, '5', '55'),
    (NULL, '6', '70'),
    (NULL, '1', '80'),
    (NULL, '2', '90'),
    (NULL, '3', '65'),
    (NULL, '4', '55'),
    (NULL, '5', '45'),
    (NULL, '6', '60'),
    (NULL, '1', '35'),
    (NULL, '2', '61'),
    (NULL, '3', '99'),
    (NULL, '4', '66'),
    (NULL, '5', '55'),
    (NULL, '6', '33'),
    (NULL, '1', '88'),
    (NULL, '2', '15'),
    (NULL, '3', '20'),
    (NULL, '4', '29'),
    (NULL, '5', '36'),
    (NULL, '6', '58');
```

This is the sample above. I added the 4 table, Apostadores, Depositos, Saque and Contas.
I've tried with DISTINCT with no success.

EDIT 2:
If I try the query below I can get the right value for all rows, but if I do one more join as below query, it bring the wrong value

```
SELECT a.Nome
      ,c.Saldo
      ,COUNT(d.ID)
FROM Apostadores a
LEFT JOIN Contas c ON a.ID = c.Apostador_ID
LEFT JOIN Depositos d ON a.ID = d.Apostador_ID
GROUP BY a.Nome, c.Saldo
```

This is the query that brings wrong values.

```
SELECT a.Nome
      ,c.Saldo
      ,COUNT(d.ID)
      ,COUNT(s.ID)
FROM Apostadores a
LEFT JOIN Contas c ON a.ID = c.Apostador_ID
LEFT JOIN Depositos d ON a.ID = d.Apostador_ID
LEFT JOIN Saques s ON a.ID = s.Apostador_ID
GROUP BY a.Nome, c.Saldo
```

Comment: What should be 27? `Depositos` and/or `Saques`? Sample data (that produced the given result) might really help to understand what you're trying to do too...

Comment: If you can share sample data, it will be helpful to solve your query.

Comment: sample was added, all of four tables

Answer (score 0):

To have the same result you need to include the sum aggregate function for the Saldo attribute

```
SELECT a.Nome
      ,SUM(c.Saldo)
      ,COUNT(d.Apostador_ID) AS Depositos
      ,COUNT(s.Apostador_ID) AS Saques
FROM Apostadores a
LEFT JOIN Contas c ON a.ID = c.Apostador_ID
LEFT JOIN Deposito d ON a.ID = d.Apostador_ID
LEFT JOIN Saque s ON a.ID = s.Apostador_ID
GROUP BY a.Nome
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are joining along different dimensions.  And, `count()` simply counts non-`NULL` values.

Often the best solution is to aggregate *before* you `JOIN`. 
 A simple solution, though, is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT a.Nome, c.Saldo
       COUNT(DISTINCT d.id) AS Depositos
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) AS Saques
FROM Apostadores a LEFT JOIN
     Contas c
     ON a.ID = c.Apostador_ID LEFT JOIN
     Deposito d
     ON a.ID = d.Apostador_ID LEFT JOIN
     Saque s
     ON a.ID = s.Apostador_ID
GROUP BY a.Nome, c.Saldo
```

Comment: This query returning: 
Nome Saldo Depositos Saque 
Marcela -3512 1 1 
Marcos 4857 1 1 
Maria -3359 1 1 
Mariana 8348 1 1 
Mario -2367 1 1 
Paulo 2868 1 1 

It is not actually counting am sum all values :/

Comment: @OracyMartos . . . You want to count the `id`s in those tables.  I revised the query.  It helps that you edited the question to include the definitions of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I changed something on query below that I have no idea what, and it is working now!!

Thank you for your help!!

```
SELECT a.Nome
      ,c.Saldo
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT d.ID) AS Depositos
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT s.ID) AS Saques
      ,SUM(d.Valor_Depositado) AS Valor_Depositado
      ,SUM(s.Valor_Sacado) AS Valor_Sacado
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT t.ID) AS Transferencias_Efetuadas
      ,SUM(t.Valor_Transferido) AS Valor_Enviado_Transferencia
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT ap.ID) AS Quantidade_Apostas
      ,SUM(ap.Valor_Apostado) AS Valor_Apostado
FROM Apostadores a
LEFT JOIN Contas c ON a.ID = c.Apostador_ID
LEFT JOIN Depositos d ON a.ID = d.Apostador_ID
LEFT JOIN Saques s ON a.ID = s.Apostador_ID
LEFT JOIN Transferencias t ON a.ID = t.Origem_Apostador_ID
LEFT JOIN Apostas ap ON a.ID = ap.Apostador_ID
GROUP BY a.Nome, c.Saldo
```